# How to avoid Thunderbird exceeding email account bandwidth limit?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

Since a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 I get messages from Thunderbird that my
email account has exceeded bandwidth limits. I use IMAP access my email and I have never had this problem before but I notice that Thunderbird never really finishes downloading messages. My bandwidth limit is 2.5 GB per day and Thunderbird keeps hitting the limit between being suspended due to hitting it.

How can I avoid reaching the bandwidth limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid this is to uncheck "Keep messages for this account on the computer" which is found under Synchronization & Storage in the Account settings for the affected email account.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might be hitting this bug: [#1068921:
Mailbox grows endlessly, heavy traffic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1068921). This has been fixed in the 16.0.2 update to thunderbird, which is in the archive for quantal now.

You should be able to upgrade through the Ubuntu Software Updater or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And check which version you have installed at the moment:

```
dpkg -l thunderbird
```

Comment: I do no think 16.0.2 fixes is as I have had 16.0.2+build since it was release and the problem still occurs with it. [Disabling "Keep messages for this account on the computer"](http://askubuntu.com/a/209959/19490) helped though.